# Sumar y restar cadenas en Java sin array

Tags: java, poo

necesito sumar una cadena que el usuario insterte ej. 1+2+3-1-2 y hacer la operacion con su respuesta , me salio la suma pero no logro adjuntarle la resta , el ejercicio no deja usar array. espero que me puedan ayudar.Esto es lo que llevo:

```
    public String sumalineal (String cadena) {
    int suma=0;
    String numero="";
    char signo='+';

    for (int x=0; x<cadena.length(); x++) { //numero de caracteres de la cadena
        if (cadena.charAt(x)== signo) {
            suma=suma + Integer.parseInt(numero);
            numero="";
        }
        else {
            numero=numero+Character.toString(cadena.charAt(x));
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(suma+Integer.parseInt(numero));
}
public String restalineal(String cadena) {
    int resta=0;
    String numero="";
    char signo='-';
    for (int x=0; x<cadena.length();x++) {
        if (cadena.charAt(x)== signo) {
            resta=resta-Integer.parseInt(numero);
            numero=" "; 
        else{
            if (cadena.charAt(x)==signo){
                resta = resta - Integer.parseInt(numero);
                numero=" ";
            }
            numero=numero+Character.toString(cadena.charAt(x));
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(resta+Integer.parseInt(numero));
```

}
}

Comment: Pero qué se supone que pasas como parámetro a la función sumalineal?  porque si le pasas esto "1+2+3-1-2", cuando encuentre el "-" lo tratará de convertir a un número y quién sabe que hará.

Comment: Eso no es Array, es substring

Comment: Johan Donado, solo paso cadenas de suma como 1+2+3 , pero necesito que mi programa resuelva una cadena con suma y resta como 1+3+5-2-1, solo que no logro hacerlo.

Comment: Veo errores en restaLineal. Lo primero es que cuando haces una resta, luego seteas `numero = " "`. Ese espacio en blanco te dará problemas a la hora de parsear a Int. Luego la condición dentro del for no tiene sentido; me refiero a la segunda, que es idéntica la primera pero en la parte del else. Me refiero a `if (cadena.charAt(x)==signo)` que esta después del else

Comment: Ademas me he dado cuenta de un detalle muy importante. En tus metodos, en la primera iteracion haces un `suma+numero`, teniendo  `suma=0` y `numero` el primer digito del arrray. Esto funciona en la suma. En la resta no vale, ya que en este caso harías un `resta-numero` y si hemos pasado como cadena `10-2-3-1`, derrepente convertirá el 10 en -10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí esta mi solución para procesar sumas y restas simultáneamente

```
public String operacionLineal(String cadena)
{
    final char SUMA='+';
    final char RESTA='-';
    boolean firstSign=true;
    char lastOp='+';
    int operacion=0;        
    String numero = "";



    for (int x = 0; x < cadena.length(); x++) { // numero de caracteres de la cadena


        if (cadena.charAt(x) == SUMA || cadena.charAt(x) == RESTA) {
            if(firstSign)//Solo lo usamos para la primera operacion
            {
                operacion = Integer.parseInt(numero);
                firstSign=false;        
            }
            else
            {
                if(lastOp == SUMA)
                {
                    //Suma
                    operacion = operacion + Integer.parseInt(numero);

                }
                else
                {
                    //Resta
                    operacion = operacion - Integer.parseInt(numero);

                }
            }
            lastOp=cadena.charAt(x);//Almacenamos la ultima operacion

            numero = "";
        } else {
            numero = numero + Character.toString(cadena.charAt(x));
        }
    }


    // sumamos/restamos el ultimo digito
    if(lastOp == SUMA)
    {
        //Suma
        operacion = operacion + Integer.parseInt(numero);

    }
    else
    {
        //Resta
        operacion = operacion - Integer.parseInt(numero);

    }
    return Integer.toString(operacion);
}
```

Basemonos en tu ejemplo 1+2+3-1-2 para la explicacion. En tu codigo, realizabas la operacion de suma/resta, en cuanto recibías un signo. Así que cuando llegas a la segunda operacion, llenas una suma de `3` y toca sumarle un 3, esperas a recibir el siguiente signo, pero este es el `-`. Con el camino que seguia tu codigo, se habria hecho un ´-3´, cosa que no es correcto.

Por eso en mi código, se conserva la ultima operación (variable `lastOp`), para que cuando recibimos un símbolo, hacemos la operación con el simbolo anterior (el correcto) y pasamos a guardar el nue como `lastOp`

Comment: Gracias a todos , me ha servido mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te sirva mi solución:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(processStringOperation("20+3-10+2+6"));
    }

    public static int processStringOperation(String operation) {
        char operator = '\0';
        String operand = "";
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < operation.length(); i++) {
            char c = operation.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                operand += c;
            } else {
                // Es la primera vez que aparece un operador, de modo que se trata
                // del primer operando
                if (operator == '\0') {
                    result = Integer.parseInt(operand);
                } else {
                    result = addOrSubstract(result, operator, Integer.parseInt(operand));
                }

                operator = c;
                operand = "";
            }
        }

        return addOrSubstract(result, operator, Integer.parseInt(operand));
    }

    public static int addOrSubstract(int a, char operator, int b) {
        if (operator == '+') {
            return a + b;
        } else {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```